# XMLString needs to change the format

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

my xml DATA IS like:(This is xmlstring not an xmlfile and i need to transform without saving....)

```
 <ProductGroups>
 <ProductGroup>
 <Name>ABC</Name>
 <Id>123</Id>
 </ProductGroup>
 <ProductGroup>
 <Name >xyz</Name>
 <Id>456</Id>
 </ProductGroup>
 <ProductGroup>
 <Name>PQR</Name>
 <Id>789</Id>
 </ProductGroup>
     .
     .
 </ProductGroups>
```

I want to transform like this

```
<PRODUCTGROUPS>
<Name ID="123"> ABC</NAME>
<Name ID="456"> XYZ</NAME>
<Name ID="789">PQR</NAME>
   .
   .
</PRODUCTGROUPS>
```

I'm using C# with .NET.

Comment: What have you tried? And if you want to transform XML have you considered [XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx) (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations)?

Comment: Please don't transform `ProductGroups` into `PRODUCTGROUPS`.

Comment: which bit are you struggling with?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: It appears to be an artifact from the user's tendency to switch to caps randomly. See the original revision. Still, good call.

Comment: @Henk Holterman:I won't change ProductGroups to PRODUCTGROUPS. Thank you for your valueable advise.

Comment: @BoltClock: Good observation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory, may contain some errors:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var groups = doc.Descendants(ProductGroup);

var newDoc = new XElement("ProductGroups", 
    groups.Select(pg => new XElement("Name", 
            new XAttribute("Id", pg.Element("Id").Value), 
            pg.Element("Name").Value) ));


newDoc.Save(...);
```

Comment: @melanie: when you have an XML _string_ , use `XDocument.Parse(str)`. Load is for files or URLs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with linq2xml : (EDIT : roughly the same aproach as Henk Holterman)

```
XDocument sourceDocument = XDocument.Load("D:\\XmlFile.xml");

XDocument targetDocument = new XDocument();
var productGroupsElement = new XElement("ProductGroups");
sourceDocument.Descendants("ProductGroup").ToList().ForEach(productGroup =>
{
    if (productGroup.Element("Name") != null && productGroup.Element("Id") != null)
    {
        var nameElement = new XElement("Name", productGroup.Element("Name").Value);
        nameElement.Add(new XAttribute("Id", productGroup.Element("Id")));
        productGroupsElement.Add(nameElement);
    }
});

targetDocument.Add(productGroupsElement);
var resultXml = targetDocument.ToString(SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: XDocument sourceDocument = XDocument.Load(ReturnXml);
 SOURCEDOCUMENT REMAINS NULL!!!

Comment: If you put in a string instead of a file on disk, use XDocument.Parse(ReturnXml);

Comment: It is also wise to learn from the code that ppl write for you instead of just pasting it and progressing towards the next "problem" you encounter. By investigating the code you could have easily figured this out yourself while the Load and Parse methods on XDocument are well commented.